# Complicated double sum using "outer"

Tags: r

I have to calculate the following in R

[image]

where kip, c are constants. One way of doing this is like:

```
xfun<- function(x,k,p,c){
ghhh<-numeric()
for(i in 1: length(x)){
ghhh[i]<-sum(k/(x[i]-x[1:(i-1)]+c)^p)
}
res<-sum(log(ghhh))
return(res)
}
```

. But can I calculate this using "outer" ? So that it becomes faster?

The data is like:

```
t <- numeric(2000)
t[1]<-0
for (i in 2:2000){
t[i]<- t[i-1]+rexp(1, 0.2)
}
k=0.5; p=1.2; c=0.02
```

Comment: it seems easy to do it this way but when the number of observation is high, then it becomes slow. That's why I want to make it faster

Comment: Please provide example input data.

Comment: @Roland data is given.

Comment: What is taking time ? is your real dataset `t` bigger ? or do you have to test it by changing these parameters a lot ? which of them ? this would help to know how to optimize

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper the length of "t" is very big. Suppose I have 10000 observations. For each observation t[i]; I have to calculate  [i-1] calculations and then sum over them. I have to do this for each of the observations and then have to take final sum. That's why it is taking time.

Comment: OK, unrelated but I think you forgot the `log` in your code :)

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  yes, thank you.

Comment: One thing that I wonder, for i = 1, you have the inner sum from j = 1 to 0 which is by definition zero and then you take the log of it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is a bit confusing. I'm not sure what should happen in the inner sum if i == 1. Sum from 1 to zero?

Based on some guessing (if I guessed wrong, you need to adjust the following), I suspect your function should be corrected to this:

```
xfun<- function(x,k,p,c){
  ghhh<-numeric() # it would be better practice to use numeric(length(x) - 1)
  for(i in 1: (length(x) - 1)){
    ghhh[i]<-sum(k/(x[i+1]-x[1:i]+c)^p)
  }
  res<-sum(log(ghhh))
  return(res)
}

t <- numeric(2000)
t[1]<-0
set.seed(42)
for (i in 2:2000){
  t[i]<- t[i-1]+rexp(1, 0.2)
}
k=0.5; p=1.2; c=0.02
xfun(t, k, p, c)
#[1] -1526.102
```

Rewritten with `outer`:

```
xfun1 <- function(x ,k ,p ,c){

  o <- outer(seq_along(x), seq_along(x), function(i, j) {
    res <- numeric(length(i))
    test <- j < i
    res[test] <- k / (x[i[test]] - x[j[test]] + c) ^ p
    res
  })
  sum(log(rowSums(o)[-1]))
}

xfun1(t, k, p, c)
#[1] -1526.102
```

Benchmarking:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(loop = xfun(t, k, p, c), 
               outer = xfun1(t, k, p, c),
               times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  loop 186.0454 186.2375 188.9567 187.4005 189.0597 196.6992    10  a 
# outer 263.4137 274.6610 346.4505 344.6918 423.3651 425.2885    10   b
```

As you see, the solution with `outer` is not faster for data of this size. The main reasons are that R needs to allocate memory for a vector of length 2000^2 and work on this large vector. Also, your simple loop is optimized by the JIT bytecode compiler.

If you want to be faster, you need to switch to a compiled language. Luckily, this is rather easy with Rcpp:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(inline)

cppFunction(
  'double xfun2(const NumericVector x, const double k, const double p, const double c) {
     int n = x.length() - 1;
     NumericVector ghhh(n);
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       for (int j = 0; j <= i ; ++j) {
         ghhh(i) += k / pow(x(i + 1) - x(j) + c, p);
       }
     }
     ghhh = log(ghhh);
     double res;
     res = sum(ghhh);
     return res;
  }')

xfun2(t, k, p, c)
#[1] -1526.102

microbenchmark(loop = xfun(t, k, p, c), 
               outer = xfun1(t, k, p, c),
               Rcpp =  xfun2(t, k, p, c),
               times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  loop 186.0395 188.7875 189.7487 189.9298 191.6967 192.7213    10  b 
# outer 408.4452 416.7730 432.3356 419.7510 422.4000 559.4279    10   c
#  Rcpp 136.1496 136.1606 136.1929 136.1762 136.2129 136.3089    10 a
```

As you see, speed gains are minimal for data of this size (JIT compilation is truly marvelous). I suggest to stay with your R loop.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the logic you implement is the correct one you could try the parallel R functionalities:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

xfun2<- function(x,k,p,c){

  no_cores <- detectCores() - 1
  cl<-makeCluster(no_cores)
  registerDoParallel(cl)      
  ghhh <- foreach(i  = 1: length(x), .combine = c) %dopar% sum(k/(x[i]-x[1:(i-1)]+c)^p)
  res <- sum(log(ghhh))

}
```

I ran it with `x <- rnorm(100000, 1, 0.5)` and the parallel version was almost twice as fast. 
You can read more about the doParallel package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf)